# magento 2 get product sale count using custom module

Tags: magento2, product, sales-order, magento-2.0.6

I have created the custom module to get product sales count in product list page as well as product view page.

How can i get particular product sale count in my source file?

**I have updated my code below please check**

**Helper class:**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Helper;   
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterfac
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_reportCollectionFactory;

    CONST ENABLE = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/general/enable';
    CONST MINIMUM_COUNT = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/general/va_minimum_count';
    CONST TEXT_ALIGN = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/general/text_align';
    CONST PLP_BACKGROUNDCOLOR = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_list_page/plp_backgroundcolor';
    CONST PLP_TEXTCOLOR = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_list_page/plp_textcolor';
    CONST BORDER_RADIOUS = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_cart_radius';
    CONST PADDING_TOP_BOTTOM = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_cart_padding_tb';
    CONST PADDING_LEFT_RIGHT = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_cart_padding_lr';
    CONST FONT_SIZE = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_cart_font_size';
    CONST SALES_COUNT_TEXT = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_text';
    CONST PRODUCT_VIEW_BACKGROUND = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_background_color';
    CONST PRODUCT_VIEW_TEXT_COLOR = '[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]/product_view_page/va_proview_text_color';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\CollectionFactory $reportCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_reportCollectionFactory = $reportCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getEnable()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::ENABLE);
    }

    public function getMinimumCount()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::MINIMUM_COUNT);
    }

    public function getTextAlign()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::TEXT_ALIGN);
    }

    public function getPlpBackgroundcolor()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PLP_BACKGROUNDCOLOR);
    }

    public function getPlpTextcolor()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PLP_TEXTCOLOR);
    }

    public function getBorderRadious()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::BORDER_RADIOUS);
    }

    public function getPaddingTopbottom()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PADDING_TOP_BOTTOM);
    }

    public function getPaddingLeftright()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PADDING_LEFT_RIGHT);
    }

    public function getFontSize()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::FONT_SIZE);
    }

    Public function getSalesCounttext()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::SALES_COUNT_TEXT);
    }

    Public function getPviewBackground()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PRODUCT_VIEW_BACKGROUND);
    }

    Public function getPviewTextcolor()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PRODUCT_VIEW_TEXT_COLOR);
    }

    public function getSoldQtyByProductId($producID = null)
    {
        $SoldProducts = $this->_reportCollectionFactory->create();
        $SoldProdudctCOl = $SoldProducts->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $producID);
        /* If does have any product id 
         * then return false
         */
        if (!$SoldProdudctCOl->count()):
            return false;
        endif;
        echo $SoldProdudctCOl->getSelect()->__toString();

        $product = $SoldProdudctCOl
            ->getFirstItem();

        return (int)$product->getData('ordered_qty');
    }
}
```

**Block**:

```
<?php

namespace [Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Block\Catalog\Product;
class [ModuleName] extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_helper
            = $helper;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function getMinimumCount()
    {


        return $this->_helper->getMinimumCount();
    }

    public function getTextAlign()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getTextAlign();
    }

    public function getPlpBackgroundcolor()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPlpBackgroundcolor();

    }

    public function getPlpTextcolor()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPlpTextcolor();
    }

    public function getBorderRadious()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getBorderRadious();
    }

    public function getPaddingTopbottom()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPaddingTopbottom();
    }

    public function getPaddingLeftright()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPaddingLeftright();
    }

    public function getFontSize()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getFontSize();
    }

    Public function getSalesCounttext()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getSalesCounttext();
    }

    Public function getPviewBackground()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPviewBackground();
    }

    Public function getPviewTextcolor()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getPviewTextcolor();
    }

    Public function getSaleCount()
    {

        //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        //$id = $product->getId();
        $productId = 1;

        return $this->_helper->getSoldQtyByProductId($productId);

        //echo $product->getName();

    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->_helper->getEnable()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Model\[File_name]');
        $collection = $model->getCollection();

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

**view.phtml**:

```
<div class="vendorname-Modulename-block" style="text-align:
<?= $this->getTextAlign() ?>;
    background-color:<?= $this->getPviewBackground() ?>;color:
<?= $this->getPviewTextcolor() ?>;font-size:
<?= $this->getFontSize() ?>px;border-radius:
<?= $this->getBorderRadious() ?>px; padding:
<?= $this->getPaddingTopbottom() ?>px
<?= $this->getPaddingLeftright() ?>px; width:70%;">
    <h3 class="label"><?= $this->getSaleCount() ?>
        <?= $this->getSalesCounttext() ?></h3>
</div>
```

Here everything working fine like colors, etc., but i cannot able to get sales count here.

When i use `$producID == null` in `public function getSoldQtyByProductId()` i got below error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')'
>   in magento2\app\code[Vendorname][ModuleName]\Helper\Data.php on line
>   84

Comment: what is logic behind count of sales of a products?

Comment: i want to get particular  product sale count ,and want to display that count to category list page and product view page

Comment: same like what we have used in magento 1  Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()

Comment: waiting i have checking and get back  to  you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case,you need to ***create module which has a Helper***.

At *this helper class* have a **function** `getSoldQtyByProductId($productid)`.,which will ***give you no of sold products basic of order placed.***

### Helper class:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_reportCollectionFactory;    
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\CollectionFactory  $reportCollectionFactory
    ) {
    $this->_reportCollectionFactory = $reportCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getSoldQtyByProductId($producID=null){
        $SoldProducts= $this->_reportCollectionFactory->create();
        $SoldProdudctCOl=$SoldProducts->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $producID);
        /* If does have any product id 
         * then return false
         */
        if(!$SoldProdudctCOl->count()):
                    return false;
        endif;
        echo $SoldProdudctCOl->getSelect()->__toString();

        $product = $SoldProdudctCOl
                        ->getFirstItem();

        return (int)$product->getData('ordered_qty');
    }
}
```

**Now get  Qty by below code:**

```
$_helper = $this->_helper = $this->helper('[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Helper\Data');
$_helper->getSoldQtyByProductId($productId);
```

Comment: hello Amit..i have update my code above, kindly check it.

Comment: still i cannot able to get sales count.

Comment: syntax mistake `getSoldQtyByProductId($producID==null)`  should be `getSoldQtyByProductId($producID=null)`

Comment: yes Amit  i  used  like getSoldQtyByProductId($producID=null) but i did not get any count

Comment: Hi Amit Bera is there any updates?

Comment: Amit product sale count working fine thanks

Comment: i accepted i have  few more doubts in that ,In need sale count with order status as COMPLETE

Comment: I want to get sales count when order status is COMPLETE

Comment: i will check  and get back to you at night

Comment: i got it Thank you "$SoldProdudctCOl=$SoldProducts->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $producID)->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete');"

Comment: How to get product sale count based on website